# Anchor link text not highlighting on focus in Firefox on Mac

Tags: css, firefox

A login page I have, is working correctly with highlighted anchor links on focus when tabbing through the inputs. In Firefox on Mac, it is not working. This is the code I have that works in Chrome/FF/IE on Windows.

```
.forgot-password-link a:focus{
        background: yellow;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: What is not working ? The looking of the focused link ? The focus event ? Have you tried precising the color of the border : `border: 1px solid black` ?

Comment: When the user tabs through the login screen, going from the password field to remember me and forgot password links, the style of the forgot password link is not showing the styles attributed to it by the style sheet class.